# Want to print string with jquery $.load

Tags: javascript, php

I am using jquery to load a php file within javascript and I want to print a string with it like this but didn't work with me in this way!:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(function () {
  $(".TempStatus" + " &deg;C").load('tempr.php')

 }, 3000);
</script>
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Looks like you've already achieved it. Or, have you already run into a problem you're not telling us about?

Comment: FYI: `".TempStatus" + " &deg;C" === ".TempStatus &deg;C"`

Comment: What HTML element(s) is `$(".TempStatus" + " &deg;C")` meant to select?  And why concatenate two string literals instead of just using one string literal?  What's the actual problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't append the string to the selector. You need to append the string to the DOM element in a callback function.

```
$(".TempStatus").load('tempr.php', function() {
    $(this).append(" &deg;C");
});
```

You could also use `$.get()` instead of `$.load()` and concatenate in the callback function:

```
$.get("tempr.php", function(temp) {
  $(".TempStatus").html(temp + " &deg;C");
});
```

A simpler solution would be to just put `&deg;C` in your HTML, outside the element you're loading, e.g.

```
Temperature: <span class="TempStatus"></span> &deg;C
```

Comment: thank you very much I solved it with `$.get` thank you again :)